# React.js: как найти элемент по id или class после события setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

После onClick я делаю this.setState, и новые данные хочу перезаписать в div, но для этого мне нужно найти этот div на странице.
document.querySelector('.class') - не помогает, пишет ошибку :

> Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .1.$0.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like ,
>
> , or , or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID `.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.1`.

Если не ошибасю, то React.findDOMNode не ищет по id или class.

Как я могу в таком случае найти нужный элемент с нужным классом и перезаписать в него значения, вот таким образом?

```
var li = <li>{this.state.test.map(function (elem, i) {
        return <li key={i}><a href="#">{elem}</a></li>;
    })}</li>;

    React.render(li, document.querySelector('.class'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState`
Работает только в области видимости Вашего компонента и записывает всё в state, поэтому не получится присвоить значение через данный метод.

Попробуйте просто на событие onClick внести значение через jquery:

```
$('.class')[0].html(data);
```

Хотя это не слишком хороший способ. Лучше всего если `<div>` в который Вы хотите внести данные будет находится внутри компонента. Таким образом обеспечивается модульность и связанность данных.

Answer (score 0):

Вы на самом деле сейчас нарушаете философию *React*. Почему бы вам не создать отдельный компонент для вашего блока, куда должны передаваться данные и у него изменяйте состояние. 

Можете, конечно, придумать какой-нибудь роутер, или как выше предлагали использовать JQ прямо в обработчике, но это не по React-овски.